# Missing root CA certificates in Ubuntu

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl, certificates

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed on my remote Google VM. It is missing some critical root CA certificates which is causing verification error on `curl`, `wget` and `apt-get`. How do I install the missing certificates?

Missing certificates details - https://www.diffchecker.com/EmoV1UFQ
[image]

The certificates on the right (in green) are missing in my Ubuntu server. I used the following command to get the list of ca certificates.

```
awk -v cmd='openssl x509 -noout -subject' '
    /BEGIN/{close(cmd)};{print | cmd}' < /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

The other server is running Debian Linux which I used to compare the certificates list. I tried reinstalling the certificates on Ubuntu using the following command, however, it just reinstalled the same certificates again. Missing certificates still remain missing.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates 

sudo apt-get -f install

sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends ca-certificates
sudo apt-get -f install
```